# How to Show Highchart on popup page [triggered by button]

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, highcharts

Can anyone help to solved this problem.
I have two file .php (page.php & chart.php)
I want to make the chart show up as Pop up page, but somehow it doesn't work. 
this is my first time I create hightchart.
page.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <?php include 'chart.php ';?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

chart.php

```
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welcome.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        $('#days').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Days Frequency'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Days Frequency',
                data: [
                    ['Monday',   4],
                    ['Tuesday',       2],
                    ['Wednesday',    1],
                    ['Thursday',     1],
                    ['Friday',   2]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });

});
</script> 
    <title>Behaviour Insight</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="home.html"><div class="header">
        </div><!--end header -->
                    <div id="days"></div>
    </div><!--end container -->
</body>

</html>
```

how can I make the chart show up in the pop up.
thanks

Comment: what's the relation to php?

Comment: Maybe some master php can handle this, like using content or etc.. :(

Comment: php is serverside, it doesn't handle popups, js does

Comment: it was just sample prototype, I would like to use in my design dashboard if I have a clue,,, thanks @Fred-ii- can you help me.

Comment: I'm not your guy for this, sorry. I'm 99% serverside.

Comment: so how can I use this concept? is there any different method? I want to show the chart as pop up page, not as full page. do you have suggestion or idea?

Answer (score 0):

change chart.php to just this...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Build the chart
            $('#days').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Days Frequency'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Days Frequency',
                        data: [
                            ['Monday', 4],
                            ['Tuesday', 2],
                            ['Wednesday', 1],
                            ['Thursday', 1],
                            ['Friday', 2]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    });
</script> 

<div class="container">
    <a href="home.html"></a>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div id="days"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you replace <?php include 'chart.php ';?>  in page.php with the contents of the chart.php (as shown in my answer), does it work?

Comment: i see an idea from your statement, but with different method, I try to using iframe instead of the content. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap model](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) to have same functionality of pop up and show highcharts maps in modal body

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/r8zxybfr/) for demonstration

Your chart.php can be (in idea)

Html

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
  },


  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
  }, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
  }, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
  }]

});
```